# Create log file when running a windows script file

Tags: windows, windows-scripting

I am running a windows script file, via a task scheduler, which carries out some basic tasks. I need to record each command in a temporary log file.

I have seen some examples on the web, but most seem to suggest having each command line tagged with the >> marker. This is tedious for my scripts, have over 100 commands. 
Is there a way to do what I want to do, with some global commands in the script file

Many thanks
ash

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (This is not related to the SQL language.)

Comment: An example would be helpful, and this isn't really a SQL issue - this appears to be a windows command script issue.